# Cannot change value of member variable

Tags: c++, oop

In my program I have a class called ShaderManager that encapsulates all the GLSL shaders that I use, and ShaderManager::LoadShader() is supposed to increment the number of available shaders (shaderCount) every time it is called.

The problem is that `shaderCount++;`  does not increase the value of shaderCount (an unsigned int). shaderCount will be 0, and it will stay zero even after the increment operation. Same problem when I write out `shaderCount = shaderCount + 1`.

In ShaderManager.cpp:

```
unsigned int ShaderManager::LoadShader(const char* vertFilename, const char* fragFilename)
{

     /* ...  OpenGL code ... */

     shaderCount = shaderCount + 1;
     return shaders[shaderCount - 1];
}
```

ShaderManager::LoadShader() is not static or const.

In ShaderManager.h:

```
class ShaderManager
{

public:

    static const unsigned int MAX_SHADERS = 32;

    ShaderManager();
    ~ShaderManager();

    unsigned int LoadShader(const char* vertFilename, const char* fragFilename);
    static unsigned int GetShaderID(const unsigned int shader);



private:

    unsigned int shaderCount;
    void SetupDefaultShader();
    static unsigned int shaders[MAX_SHADERS];

};
```

Any idea of what could be happening?

Comment: Without seeing a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue, it's hard to say what the problem might be.

Comment: Good idea, I will try to recreate the problem at a smaller scope.

Comment: You should post some application code that points closer to the problem (shaderCount = shaderCount + 1; // looks good if you want to increment shaderCount)

Comment: First use a debugger to check if the function returns where you think it does (it can have another return before _++shaderCount_ or an exception trow) and second check so that you don't have another _shaderCount_ variable local in your _LoadShader_ function.

Comment: Using a static variable for `shaders`, but an instance variable for `shaderCount`, looks like trouble if you ever instantiate more than one instance of `ShaderManager`. But that doesn't look like your immediate problem. There must be something we're not seeing in this code.

Comment: Thank you so much for the comments guys! The problem was something with the Visual Studio debugger... Adding a printf showed that the value was in fact updating. I cleaned and rebuilt the project and now the correct value is being displayed. I think I'm going to have trust issues with VS now...